# rounding any number up that ends with 1

Tags: python

basically i want to round up a number to the next 10 so 44 becomes 50 any number
I've tried 
roundup = round(r8, -1)
but this only rounds normally

Comment: `num=22; num = num/10; num = round(num);`?

Comment: It gives 2 instead of 30

Comment: oops forgot to multiply with 10 and since you want to round upwards you should use `ceil` instead: `num=22; num = num/10; num = ceil(num) * 10;`

Comment: `(num+9 if num >= 0 else num) // 10 * 10`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
int(math.ceil(n / 10.)) * 10
```

Comment: How does that not provide an answer to the question?  Please read the question.